# sorting on two vertical columns

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a file that I want to sort from the nth column (which is numeric) - not the nth field.  The file looks schematically like:

```
1 Here are four words       9 8 5 
2 Here's two                7 2 6
3 One 2 3                  10 3 7
4 Guess how many are here   9 4 8
123456789012345678901234567890123
```

(where the last line is just a counter for clarity).  The good folk at stackexchange showed me that i need something like `sort -k1.27`, which *almost* does what i want.

However, where there are ties initially (as in lines 1 and 4 above;  both "9"), sort falls back to the start of the field, ranking line 1 before line 4 in this case (because "1" comes before "4"); whereas what i need is a sort *starting* at field 1.27 (i.e., one that ranks "9 4" before "9 8").

I've tried `sort -g -k1.27,1.34` [and `sort -g -k1.27,34`] but the extra argument has no evident effect...any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can define multiple *sort keys*:

```
sort -k1.27n -k1.30n
```

For ties the fall-back is a lexical comparison of the full lines.

`sort -k 1.27,1.34` would define one key that consists of the portion of the line between the 27th and 34th character of the first field. However with `-g`, that tells `sort` to consider that key as numerical, so anything past the first non-digit would be ignored.

Note that with `-k1.27`, the key is defined as starting at the 27th character of the first field *and ending at the end of the line*. With `n`, only the initial numerical part is considered.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen...but if i understand you correctly, shouldn't my "solution"  sort -g -k1.27,1.34 have worked (i.e., have sorted on columns 27:34)?

Comment: Sorry Stephen for hijacking your question, by now I should probably have added my own answer...

Comment: Okay, i'm not sure who to thank now (and i think the answer above has been edited again?), but i'm still puzzled...  Although the 'sort -k1.27 -k1.30' answer does work, if i read the responses correctly, then i'd've expected 'sort -g -k1.27' (sort using column 27 to end of line) and 'sort -g -k1.27,1.34' (sort using columns 27:34) to work...but they don't

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no worries!

Comment: @ionh The thing is that you need to define multiple keys here because numerical values stop at non-numeric characters. `-k1.27` on its own or `-k1.27,1.34` each define a single key, which only contains the first number – so on lines with ties, the second number isn't take into account.

Comment: Thanks again for the solution...i think i need yo get to get to grips with exactly what a 'key' is :-)